# Is there a Guid.TryParse for byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, guid

There is [`Guid.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse) to check whether a string contains a valid [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

There is also [the `Guid` constructor that takes a byte array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3(v=vs.110).aspx) (`byte[]`).

What I'm missing is a `TryParse` method that takes a byte array.

Currently I'm doing something like this to check whether the byte array is a valid GUID:

```
// ...
try
{
    new Guid(bytes);
    return true;
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    return false;
}
// ...
```

Of course this is bad in performance and coding style since I'm using exceptions to control program flow.

**My question:**

Is there a reasonable fast, non-exception way to check whether a byte array contains a GUID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. In fact it's quite easy to write one, you only need to ensure

1. the byte array is not null
2. the byte array's length is 16

Comment: It's not the case: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt; some `byte[16]` are not  `GUID`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If not the case, then `new Guid(byte[] b)` is also incorrect, because inside the constructor only the two requirements are checked.

Comment: Thank you! These checks seem to be similar to [Microsoft's checks](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,50), so I guess this is sufficient to check by myself.

Comment: @UweKeim Exactly. I checked the source code of FCL. But according to previous comments RFC is a little different.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Some `byte[16]`'s aren't proper GUIDs, but nobody cares about that :) There's plenty of people who (sadly) use `GUID` for numbers that *aren't* globally unique. Including many, many implementations of GUID generation that are just simple random numbers with a 32-bit seed. Oh well :) In any case, the `GUID` class doesn't care, and that seems to be the only thing Uwe cares about.